# How to fetch data in one object using Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, object, relationship

Previously I was fetching data using queries like below:

```
          $specialitiesAndRoles = DB::table('user_facility')
        ->leftjoin('roles', 'user_facility.role_id', 'roles.id')
        ->leftjoin('specialities','user_facility.speciality_id','=','specialities.id')
        ->leftjoin('available_specialties','specialities.available_specialties_id' ,'=','available_specialties.id')
        ->where('user_facility.user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('user_facility.facility_id','user_facility.speciality_id','user_facility.is_facility_supervisor','user_facility.priv_key','user_facility.role_id','specialities.name','available_specialties.id','available_specialties.specialty_key')
        ->get();

 $specialities = (object)$specialitiesAndRoles;

         $response = ['facilities' => $specialities];
```

And my response was:

```
                "facilities": [
            {
                "facility_id": 59,
                "speciality_id": 1,
                "is_facility_supervisor": 0,
                "priv_key": "can_access_patient",
                "role_id": 2,
                "name": "Medical",
                "id": 1,
                "specialty_key": "medical_doctor"
```

Now I am using relationship and trying to get the same response.

My relationship code:

```
            $specialitiesAndRoles = UserFacility::with([
        'speciality' => function($q)
        {
            $q->select('id','speciality_key');
        },
        'roles' => function($q)
        {
            $q->select('id','name');
        },
        'availableSpeciality' => function($q)
        {
            $q->select('id','specialty_key');
        }])->get();
```

And my response using relationship become in every object like below:

```
            "facilities": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 32,
                "facility_id": 59,
                "speciality_id": 1,
                "is_facility_supervisor": 0,
                "priv_key": "can_access_patient",
                "role_id": 2,
                "is_admin": null,
                "created_at": "2019-07-15 11:30:13",
                "updated_at": "2019-07-15 11:30:13",
                "isDeleted": null,
                "created_by": null,
                "updated_by": null,
                "is_primary": 0,
                "speciality": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "speciality_key": "medical_doctor"
                },
                "roles": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Admin"
                },
                "available_speciality": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "specialty_key": "accu"
                },
```

I don't want to make objects on every data from different tables, I just want to make same response which I was getting using queries and shared above.

How I can make this response using relationships?

Comment: A relationship returns a related model and it's (the related model) properties. By adding the select statements you did, all that happened was that you limited the properties to be returned. You would still need a join if you were to achieve your desired results. I think the answer provided solves that.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply change your query to this:

```
use App\Models\UserFacitily;

    $facilities = UserFacility::leftJoin('roles', 'user_facility.role_id', 'roles.id')
        ->leftJoin('specialities','user_facility.speciality_id','=','specialities.id')
        ->leftJoin('available_specialties','specialities.available_specialties_id' ,'=','available_specialties.id')
        ->where('user_facility.user_id', $user_id)
        ->select('user_facility.facility_id','user_facility.speciality_id','user_facility.is_facility_supervisor','user_facility.priv_key','user_facility.role_id','specialities.name','available_specialties.id','available_specialties.specialty_key')
        ->get();
```